# Can't read a.out file created by FORTRAN in the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, fortran

I have tried a lot of ways to compile FORTRAN on my Mac.
I used the command as the image.
But I cannot read the result after compiling.

The code is:

```
 PROGRAM Example_1_1
     REAL :: a, b, av1, av2
     READ *, a, b
             av1 = (a + b)/2; av2 = (a*b)**0.5
     PRINT *, av1, av2
 END
```

The command line is like:

```
 appledeMBP-2:test apple$ ls
 a.out      e_121_01.f90
 appledeMBP-2:test apple$ rm a.out 
 appledeMBP-2:test apple$ gfortran e_121_01.f90 
 appledeMBP-2:test apple$ ./a.out 
 q
 At line 3 of file e_121_01.f90 (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
 Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input
```

Comment: Well, `q` is not a real number... The read statement is expecting two of them... Try `1.0 2.0` for instance

Answer (score 1):

The first executable statement is to `read` `a` and `b` -- two `REAL` variables.

But all I can see you enter is the letter `q`, which is not a number. And because you haven't told the code what to do in case of an error, it stops with a concise error message: "I expected a REAL number, but didn't get one."

Run the program again, and enter two numbers, like `1.0   3.1415` and see what happens.

Comment: THX! I just wanted to run a test but didn't consider the program itself. After your explanation, I have already solved the question. THX again